# Same Signal name in asammdf

Tags: python, can-bus, mdf, asammdf

I'm using asammdf library and trying to get measurement values.
But mdf files have 4 ECUs and some signals have same name with different bus channel.

Also, I got group information but I don't know what it is.
For example, like this.
<asammdf.blocks.v4_blocks.SourceInformation object at 0x000001E46A45C180>

So, How can I know signals that came from which ECUs?

Comment: asammdf looks like the perfect name for a library that emulates a cat walking on a keyboard. Imagine my disappointment when I discovered that is a simple parser

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find the specific channels using the method `whereis` (see https://asammdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#asammdf.mdf.MDF.whereis)